# How to insert a variable into an array for every loop count and then print the array/variables in a mail?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, paypal-ipn

I have an IPN script which does a number of things and today it fetches data from PayPal and uses it to send a mail receipt to customers. PayPal has a IPN simulator which lets you simulate purchases and send these mails, only you can only send one item_name/ one product per time. Today my solution is working for at least one product, but I can not know what will happen when several products is purchased. The only way to test this is to do Live payment with real VISA for example.

I have had a similar problem with my PDT script where it was easier to test, since I could just update the pdt.php-page that users were redirected to after I made changed and uploaded the new file, but this is an email so I can not do that.

My idea is to create a empty array and with a loop for every loop count / for every product to add that current variable (item_name) into the array and then later when mail is sent to include the array-content so all items/products is shown. Is this possible? I have played around for some time but cannot get tit done, either it prints "array" or " " blank.

This is my IPN script today: http://pastebin.com/ysUsfGyf

I think to edit this key area to something like this and what I have done is set a counter to 0 ($j = 0), instantiated an empty array ($arr = array();) and tried to insert the item_name with every loop count to the array[j] which should be 0 1 2 3 and so on. Then later on when composing mail i ust added a row: $message .= "$arr"; but I havent got any good results, only empty or as "array".

```
$array_keys = array_keys($ipn_post_data);
    $count = 1;
    $i = 1;
    $j = 0;
    $arr = array();

    foreach($array_keys as $element) 
    {
        if (!strncmp('item_number', $element, strlen('item_number')))
            $count++;   

    }
        for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++ & $i++) 
        {   
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($ipn_post_data[item_name . $i]);
            $arr[$j] = $name;
        }
```

What can I change in this script or debug to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Thank! If you now add a *little* explanation sentences what your issue cause was and how you solved it would be making it a great answer. A little bit of context next to working code is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKING CODE:

```
 // send user an email with a confirmation

    $array_keys = array_keys($ipn_post_data);
    $count = 1;
    $i = 1;
    $j = 0;
    $arr = array();

    foreach($array_keys as $element) 
    {
        if (!strncmp('item_number', $element, strlen('item_number')))
            $count++;   

    }
        for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++ & $i++ & $j++) 
        {   
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($ipn_post_data[item_name . $i]);
            $arr[$j] = $name;
        }

    $arrstring = implode( ', ', $arr);
```

and later `$message .= "$arrstring";`